Transition state theory at equilibrium between reactants and products
I see that the "transition state theory" is mostly discussed for a reaction from a reactant A to a product B that is far from equilibrium, i.e. A goes to B but the reverse does not happen.
Instead, I am interested in an equilibrium between A and B:
$$ \ce{ A <=> B } $$
At equilibrium, of course, the net rate is 0, because the forward and backward reactions rates are equal. I am interested in these two equal rates, $r_\text{f}=r_\text{b}$.
In electrochemistry, this situation is common; in analogy with it, for a purely chemical reaction, I expect a rate of this form:
$$ r_\text{f} = r_\text{b} = k \ce{[A]^{\alpha} [B]^{1-\alpha}} $$
where $\alpha$ is between 0 and 1, sometimes taken around 0.5.
Have you ever seen this expression in the context of transition state theory, outside electrochemistry? Do you have a reference?

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

The link does not say anything about chemical formulas, where do I find a guide on them? Another question: the link is about MathJax, where should I not use it? In the title?

As in chemistry in general the stoichiometric equation does not necessarily describe what actually happens in the reaction. An example is $\ce{H2 + Cl2 = 2HCl}$ which is a gas phase chain reaction. Consequently much experimentation is needed to unravel the true mechanism

There are four links, not one, and they definitely talk about chemical formulas. CH SE uses by default mhchem MJ extension, involving \ce{} and \pu{} // E.g. write $\ce{H2SO4}$ to get $\ce{H2SO4}$ // $\ce{4 Fe^2+ + O2  + 4 H+ -> 4 Fe^3+ + 2 H2O}$ for $\ce{4 Fe^2+ + O2  + 4 H+ -> 4 Fe^3+ + 2 H2O}$ // $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ for $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ //  MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles. Also not to be used for simple text formatting.

The slashes looked like the subfolder separators! Can I suggest to avoid them the next time you write a set of links? I corrected the chemical equation. I did not use MathJax in the title, is everything correct now?

Non-underlined slashes wrapped by spaces cannot be confused with subfolder separators, especially if used for plain text either. Using slashes as text separators is very common in many areas. The context of the info excludes the possibility of being subfolder separator either. You are first complaining after 7-8 years. // Basically the only things in italics are symbols for one letter names of math variables and scientific quantities. that is why \text, \mathrm or \ce  are used to use upright fonts.  The F and B indexes should be upright, as they are not variables or quantities.

Corrected! Is the question now correctly formulated? Is there anything else unclear or badly explained?

Almost, you forgot about those mentioned indexes, I have fixed it. It is formally correct. // As the content is considered, for a simple reaction kinetic schema without a reaction loopback, it is highly unusual if the forward reaction rate depends on products and vice versa. // If it is an elementary reaction of the first order, it is like r_f = k_f * [A], r_b = k_b * [B], so if  r_f =  r_b then k_f * [A] = k_b * [B].

I clarified that the reaction is at equilibrium. There is no net reaction rate and the forward and backward reaction rates are the same. So, it would be unusual that they only depend on the left or right hand side of the reaction. Rigorously, there are no reactants and products, at equilibrium, but left-hand-side and right-hand-side chemicals.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If I am not mistaken, TST assumes equilibrium between A and the TS, but also poses that when the TS is reached, it can only go to B. That of course is true for the reverse. I see no reason why this could not be applied to reactions that are in equilibrium. TST uses lots of approximations, but it's still a good workhorse theory. Maybe I don't understand your question though.

The question is if the expression that I wrote, [A]^alpha [B]^(1-alpha), is used in chemistry, outside electrochemistry. In electrochemistry, it describes the passage of a barrier at equilibrium, but I know that it also holds for non-electrochemical equations. What I want to find is a reference to it, outside electrochemistry.

You say "I know that it also holds for non-electrochemical equations", so I'm assuming you are not interested in an answer about why it is not used in conventional kinetics, which would of course not lead to a reference?

Definitely, if you can explain why this expression does not appear in conventional kinetics, it would answer my question!

Let's first review the relationship between rate constants and the
equilibrium constant for a single elementary reaction $\ce{ A <=> B}$ with net rate in the
forward direction
$$
v=k_{\mathrm{f}}[\mathrm{A}]-k_{\mathrm{b}}[\mathrm{B}]
$$
At equilibium $v=0$, which leads to a relationship between the rate
constants and the equilibrium constant
$$
\frac{k_{\mathrm{f}}}{k_{\mathrm{b}}}=\frac{[\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}}{[
\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}}=K
$$
The dynamic rate at equilibrium, equal in the forward and backward
directions is
$$
v^{\mathrm{eq}}=k_{\mathrm{f}}[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}=k_{\mathrm{b}}[%
\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}
$$
In electrochemistry, the rate constants depend exponentially on potential,
and we choose a reference potential to define them relative to. Two possible
choices are the standard potential $E^{\ominus }$ or the equilibrium
(reversible) potential $E_{\mathrm{r}}$.  If the reaction is a
single-electron oxidation, the rate constants are expressed as
$$
k_{\mathrm{f}}=k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\ominus }\exp \left( \frac{(1-\beta
)F(E-E^{\ominus })}{RT}\right) =k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\mathrm{eq}}\exp \left( 
\frac{(1-\beta )F(E-E_{\mathrm{r}})}{RT}\right) 
$$
$$
k_{\mathrm{b}}=k_{\mathrm{b}}^{\ominus }\exp \left( -\frac{\beta
F(E-E^{\ominus })}{RT}\right) =k_{\mathrm{b}}^{\mathrm{eq}}\exp \left( -
\frac{\beta F(E-E_{\mathrm{r}})}{RT}\right) 
$$
where the overpotential is $\eta =E-E_{\mathrm{r}}$. (We can show that $k_{
\mathrm{f}}^{\ominus }=k_{\mathrm{b}}^{\ominus }=k^{\ominus }$.) We continue
with the second convention. We may define an electrochemical equilibrium
constant
$$
\frac{k_{\mathrm{f}}}{k_{\mathrm{b}}}=K^{\mathrm{eq}}\exp \left( \frac{F\eta 
}{RT}\right) 
$$
which at the equilibrium potential is
$$
\frac{k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\mathrm{eq}}}{k_{\mathrm{b}}^{\mathrm{eq}}}=K^{\mathrm{
eq}}=\frac{[\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}}{[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}}
$$
and
$$
v^{\mathrm{eq}}=k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\mathrm{eq}}[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}=k_{
\mathrm{b}}^{\mathrm{eq}}[\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}
$$
We (rather trivially) get the same results as in conventional kinetics. It
is significant that $\beta $, which is a kinetic parameter, does not appear
in an expression applying to equilibrium.
From the transition-state theory that led to the exponential dependence of
the rate constants, the parameter $\beta $ has the significance of
correlating the change in activation electrochemical Gibbs energy to the
change in the electrochemical Gibbs energy of the overall reaction as we
change the potential.
The nearest equivalent in conventional chemical kinetics would be something
like the Bronsted
parameter, the Bell-Evan--Polanyi
parameter or one of the other Linear Free Energy
Relationships.
Unlike variation with potential for a single reaction, they correlate the
activation energy with overall energy change for a whole series of
reactions, as something about the structure changes, such as a substituent.
This is probably the simplest reason why expressions involving these
parameters are of a different nature in chemical kinetics. (One could of
course use an $\alpha $ just for the one reaction, but then it is easier
just to use the rate constant itself.)
Suppose we decided to reference to the standard potential, i.e., we want to
use a rate constant that is not actually the one that applies at
equilibrium. Wait, that's a little crazy don't you think? You wouldn't do
that in conventional kinetics, would you? But it's electrochemistry after
all, so here goes
$$
k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\mathrm{eq}}=k^{\ominus }\exp \left( \frac{(1-\beta
)F(E_{r}-E^{\ominus })}{RT}\right) =k^{\ominus }\exp \left( \frac{
F(E_{r}-E^{\ominus })}{RT}\right) ^{(1-\beta )}
$$
From above we have $v^{\mathrm{eq}}=k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\mathrm{eq}}[\mathrm{A}
]_{\mathrm{eq}}$, so
$$
v^{\mathrm{eq}}=k_{\mathrm{f}}^{\mathrm{eq}}[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}
}=k^{\ominus }\exp \left( \frac{F(E_{r}-E^{\ominus })}{RT}\right) ^{(1-\beta
)}[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}
$$
But from the Nernst Equation, $E_{r}=E^{\ominus }+(RT/F)\ln \left( [\mathrm{B
}]_{\mathrm{eq}}/[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}\right) $, we have $\exp \left( 
\frac{F(E_{r}-E^{\ominus })}{RT}\right) =[\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}/[\mathrm{
A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}$, so
$$
v^{\mathrm{eq}}=k^{\ominus }\exp \left( \frac{F(E_{r}-E^{\ominus })}{RT}
\right) ^{(1-\beta )}[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}=k^{\ominus }\left( \frac{[
\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}}{[\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}}\right) ^{1-\beta }[
\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}=k^{\ominus }[\mathrm{B}]_{\mathrm{eq}}^{1-\beta }[
\mathrm{A}]_{\mathrm{eq}}^{\beta }
$$
which is the OP's expression in slightly different notation. The kinetic
parameter $\beta $ only appears here in an equilibrium result because we are
referencing to a potential away from the equilibrium potential. To measure $
\beta ,$ we need to carry out a measurement away from the equilibrium
potential.
The expression for $v^{\mathrm{eq}}$ (last equation) is, like many in
electrochemistry, only applicable for a single elementary reaction. Most
reactions have multistep mechanisms, so the equation has limited
applicability. Perhaps the historical focus in electrochemistry on
outer-sphere electron transfer reactions or allegedly simple reactions in
electroanalytical chemistry has led to this emphasis.
One possibly similar expression in conventional kinetics might arise if we
wanted to reference things to a different temperature than the one we were
using, since temperature makes an appearance in the exponential that occurs
when relating the rate constant to the activation energy.
